# php variable in a javascript object within a json result

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to put a php variable within a js script that is in a result variable that will be processed with json but i don't get it to work. I know it has something to do with the "" and '' but i can't figure out what it is.

```
$result["html"] .= "<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function () { window.location='.$config[\"BURL\"].'; }, 2500);</script>";
```

Edit: whoohoo i got the 15 points to upvote! Thanks u all!

Comment: Look at the output you get getting in View > Source. Determine what is wrong with it. *Then* worry about getting the PHP to output it correctly.

Comment: '".`window.location='.$config[\"BURL\"].'"`

Comment: i dont get any output

Comment: As a side point. If this is JSON, (by xhr?); wouldn't something like `$result['BURL'] = "'" . $config["BURL"] . "'"` be preferable? Do the processing of JSON `$result` client side and set timeout by JavScript instead of returning a whole document? Hard to say without knowing what you do, but only as a thought.

Comment: I've seen the way to code it like u suggest but i just return the value of $result to a DIV with jquery to another page because this one is called on the background and is only for processing. I'm not a king with English so if you want to know more pls feel free to chat since i find it very annoying to write everything here xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to concatenate strings using `.` and remove the escaping of the quotes for the index, like so:

```
$result["html"] .= "<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function () { window.location='" . $config["BURL"] . "'; }, 2500);</script>";
```